NextJS fetching old build files resulting in ERR_ABORTED 404
I have a NextJS app hosted on DigitalOcean App Platform.
When I  visit the preview link that DO provides you OR when I am in localhost, everything works fine,
however, when I am in my mydomain.com it gives me these errors. ONLY IN PRODUCTION.
enter image description here
I've tried and researched so much regarding this its driving me nuts. It's resulting in my web page not being able to update as it only fetches the old build and static files.
If i search into digital oceans's built in CLI and access the ./next folder, everything is up to date.
I tried deleting .next folder during prod and did a forced rebuild, to no avail.
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Have you tried clearing your browser cache? Or try loading the page in a private window.

Of course. This is not a local cache kind of problem. I  believe this is either CDN or nextjs code related problem. ALTHOUGHT it kind of popped out of nowhere.
I have tried on completely new devices that have never accessed my domain and it still serves the old build cache.
